# MEAN STACK "Http failure response for localhost:3700/..."

Tags: node.js, angular, http, frontend, backend

im having a problem with angular when i send a form with info to a data base(mongodb). these are the errors :

​
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }

headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }

message: "Http failure response for localhost:3700/api/save-project: 0 Unknown Error"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​

ok: false
​

status: 0
​

statusText: "Unknown Error"
​

url: "localhost:3700/api/save-project"

and the code of mi app.js and the component doing the request is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

//cargar archivos de rutas
var project_routes = require('./routes/project');

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Configurar cabeceras y cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

//rutas
app.use('/api', project_routes);

//exportar
module.exports = app;
```

angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '../../models/project';
import { projectService } from '../../services/project.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css'],
  providers: [projectService]
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
  public title: string;
  public project: Project;

  constructor( private _projectService: projectService) 
  {
    this.title = 'crear projecto';
    this.project = new Project('','','','',2019,'','');
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(form){
    console.log(this.project);
    this._projectService.saveProject(this.project).subscribe(

        response => {
               console.log(response);
        },

        error => {
               console.log(<any>error);
        }


        );

  }

}
```

this is the service that create.component use:

```
import { Injectable } from  '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from  '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from  'rxjs';
import { Project } from  '../models/project';
import { global } from './global';

@Injectable()
export class projectService
{
    public url: string;
    constructor( private _httpClient: HttpClient)
    {
        this.url = global.url;
    }

    testService(){
        return 'probando el servicio de angular';
    }

    saveProject(project: Project){

        let params = JSON.stringify(project);
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

        return this._httpClient.post(this.url + 'save-project', params, {headers:headers});
    }



}
```

thanks for your time <3